# Box shadow does not cover div

Tags: css, html-parsing

It is my first qustion :)
Box shadow does not cover drop-down ul. See the screenshot, please - http://i31.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0202/7d/83a6dfa12f24ace82a3df52b6fe0587d.png. I am trying to solve it for a several hours but no result :(
It is strange I have gave z-index to parent element 500 and to the drop-down ul 1 but shadow is still under drop-down ul not over it.
Here is the link: http://layot.prestatrend.com/
Hope someone will help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an issue regarding the [stacking context](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/37-css-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/#zindex).

The point is you can't place the block lower than the closest parent with non-static position and positive `z-index`. So, you have the `z-index:100` on the `#categories_block_top .tree li`, so you can't place the `ul` under it.

To fix that (one of the ways) you can remove this `z-index`, then add `position:relative;z-index:1;` to the `#wrapper` and then add the negative `z-index` like `z-index:-1;` to an `ul`. Doing so you'll put it on the same level as the `#wrapper`, so it would be over the content after it, but under the `box-shadow` of the `#subheader`.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend an inner (or inset) shadow on the first li element of the dropdown list.
I guess because the element will always be inside the main menu, the shadow won't work or appear above the sub list.

Comment: Prepend an inner (or inset) shadow on the first li element of the dropdown list - it will be no good looks. Because the element will always be inside the main menu, the shadow won't work or appear above the sub list - I know but even z-indexes do not solve the problem how could it be, why z-indexes do not work?

Comment: The drop-down is a child of the element with the box-shadow. Therefore, z-index will not aid you with a solution in this case.

Comment: I'm trying to get a gradient working for you, that will mimic the shadow. @VinnyBurgh Same as I thought :) And kizu's solution should work indeed, I didn't think of it, sorry. Hope you'll manage.